# How can I use a Tk textbox to select and graph different datasets?

Tags: python, graph, tkinter

I am a Python 2.7 / Tk newbie trying to create a gui for displaying graphs from different data files. The skeleton program below uses an Entry widget to take names "data1" and "data2". By default, the graph for data1 appears. I want the graph to change to data2 when a person enters "data2" and presses Return.

I have tried doing this with and without classes, with no luck.

I have also tried using a Button, but haven't succeeded with that either.

Why does dataname = etr.get() not work?

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Label, Entry, Button, TOP, LEFT, BOTH #, Canvas, Frame, W, N, E, S

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np

def plot_data(fig, dat_name):
    t = np.arange(10)
    v1 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,4,4]
    v2 = [4,4,4,4,5,4,4,3,2,1]
    if dat_name[4] == 2:
        y = v2
    else:
        y = v1
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot(t,y, color='red')
    a.set_title('Graph of ')    
    a.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    a.set_ylabel('voltage (mv)')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x250+200+200")
dataname = 'data1'

f = Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=72)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

#plot_data(f, dataname)

lbl = Label(root, text='Current data:  ')
lbl.pack(side=LEFT)

etr = Entry(root, width=20)
etr.pack(side=LEFT)
etr.delete(0, last=None)
etr.insert(0, dataname) # What is the first parameter for???
dataname = etr.get()

#etr_entry.bind("<Return>", entry_handler)
#btn = Button(root, text = 'Open', command=entry_handler)
#btn.pack(side=LEFT)

plot_data(f, dataname)
print('dataname = '+dataname)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you provide please an example of input data ? And maybe a sketch of expected results ?

Comment: This program is for displaying electrocardiogram data, voltage signals from the heart, as time series with thousands of samples. The data is in text files that I can read in and display. (See data-heart.png example). For the purpose of my question, I have created two arbitrary lists v1 and v2 as examples of two different data sets. They should display as data1.png and data2.png.

Comment: Maybe out of the scope of your need, but usually when I need to generate some plots, I call GNUPLOT from my python scrip, generate image file, and then load them in the GUI if needed. Anyway, I'll take a look at the matplotlib graph displayer and try o come with a answer later.

Comment: It looks like I cannot post images until I have a reputation of 10. Sorry.

Comment: you may add a link, therer exists some image hosting service such as https://imageshack.com/

Comment: One note: It's important that the graphs rescale with adjustments to the window size. That's why I use fig.add_subplot(111) from matplotlib.figure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here come a solution that is working :

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Label, Entry, Button, TOP, LEFT, BOTH #, Canvas, Frame, W, N, E, S

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np

class ECG_Dsiplayer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        master.bind("<c>", lambda x : self.clean())#allow to test the clean function, press "c"
        master.bind("<Return>", lambda x : self.draw_data())

        self.datasetName = tk.StringVar()
        self.datasetName.set("data1") #default value
    # ____________________________________________________  
    def draw_data(self):
        self.clean()
        self._createWidgets()
        self.plot_ecg_data()
    # ____________________________________________________
    def plot_ecg_data(self):
        values = self._load_data(self.datasetName.get())
        a = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(np.arange(len(values)),values, color='red')
        a.set_title('Graph of ')    
        a.set_xlabel('time (s)')
        a.set_ylabel('voltage (mv)')
    # ____________________________________________________
    def _createWidgets(self):
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=72)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.label = Label(self, text='Current data:  ')
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.datasetEntry = Entry(self, width=20, textvariable=self.datasetName)
        self.datasetEntry.pack(side=LEFT)
    # ____________________________________________________  
    def _load_data(self, dataName):
        ## TO OVERRIDE IN ORDER TO PROVIDE A TRUE DATA LOADING SYSTEM ##
        if dataName == "data1":
            return [1,2,3,4,5,4,4,4,4,4]
        else:
            return [4,4,4,4,5,4,4,3,2,1]
    # ____________________________________________________  
    def clean(self):
        for widget in self.pack_slaves():
            widget.pack_forget()
    # ____________________________________________________


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x250+200+200")    

    ecg = ECG_Dsiplayer(root)
    ecg.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    ecg.draw_data()

    root.mainloop()
```

Please take note of the following points :

- Your test to check which of the dataset to use was bugged. It always returned the same value, so you problem is probably coming from this line. `if dat_name[4] == 2:` is always False as you are trying to compare an integer value to a string one.
- You should try to use more explicit variable name. I make some refactoring here, but the overall code readability is still to improve!
- You should try to use the grid manager instead of the pack one. The pack manager allow to build fastly the GUI, but the grid one provide better control on what's happen. Here the use of a grid manager would allow to delete only the canvas widget and let the other untouched. It so allow to move the entry and label code in the init method and never be called again. With pack if not deleted, they go up to the drawing at the second call to draw data.

Finally, have fun with python, and good luck!

Arthur.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur, thank you very much for your answer. You have made many good suggestions. In the meantime, I have continued working, formulating a  new class CardioGUI. Finally, I obtained the following result:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img661/3842/zTESMt.png

Here is my code so far (Displays graphs, though still buggy)

```
import numpy as np

from Tkinter import Label, Button, StringVar, LEFT, TOP, BOTH
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk

def destroy(e): sys.exit()

#root.bind("<Destroy>", destroy)

class CardioGUI:
    LABEL_TEXT = [
        "Example-30s",
        "Example-120s",
        "David-counting",
        "Cynthia-following",
        "Miriam-reading"
     ]
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Cardiorespiratory GUI")
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=72)
#        self.f.set_facecolor('red')

        self.label_index = 0
        self.label_text = StringVar()
        self.label_text.set(self.LABEL_TEXT[self.label_index])
#        plot_data(self.label_text.get())

        self.cvs = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=root)
        self.cvs.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.cvs._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.lbl1 = Label(master, text='Data') # Non-interactive label
        self.lbl1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lbl2 = Label(master, width=30, textvariable=self.label_text)
        self.lbl2.bind("<Button-1>", self.cycle_label_text)
        self.lbl2.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.btn1 = Button(master, text='Plot data')
        self.btn1.bind("<Button-1>", \
          lambda label_text: plot_data(self.label_text.get()))
        self.btn1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Analyze", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack(side=LEFT)

    def greet(self):
        print("Analyse!")

    def cycle_label_text(self, event):
        self.label_index += 1
        self.label_index %= len(self.LABEL_TEXT) # wrap around
        self.label_text.set(self.LABEL_TEXT[self.label_index])
        plot_data(label_text.get())

def plot_data(session_name):
    a = my_gui.f.add_subplot(211)
    b = my_gui.f.add_subplot(212)

    my_gui.cvs.show()

    filepath = 'C:/Users/David/My Documents/Cardiorespiratory Experiment/data/'
    fullfilename = filepath+session_name+'.txt'

    data = np.loadtxt(fullfilename, skiprows=7, usecols=(0,1,2))
    t = [row[0] for row in data]    
    v = [row[1] for row in data]
    p = [row[2] for row in data]

    a.plot(t,v, color='red')
    a.set_title('Heartbeat and Respiration')
    a.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    a.set_ylabel('voltage (mv)')
    b.plot(t,p)
    b.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    b.set_ylabel('pressure (kpa)')
    return # Unclear whether this is needed


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x250+100+100")
my_gui = CardioGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```